# vue 3, ts, vite out of memory

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, quasar-framework

I'm using vue3 in combination with Typescript and Vite. If I run the project via `npm run dev` everything is working as expected. The build command `npm run build` doesn't throw any error but if I try to load the page in the browser `npm run preview` only a part of the page gets rendered and after a minute an `OutOfMemory` Exception occures. There is no Log output in the console and while trying to load the browser dev tools stopped working.

vite.config.ts

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
 build: {
   minify: false,
   sourcemap: false,
 },
 plugins: [
   vue({
     template: { transformAssetUrls }
 }),

 quasar({
   sassVariables: 'src/quasar-variables.sass'
 })
],
resolve: {
 alias: {
  '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
 }
}
})
```

Any ideas?